# pushing a var of numbers that are strings into an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, variables

I have a variable that looks like the following:

```
my_var = "123, 222, 333, 444, 555, 1024, 44444"
```

Having a hard time figuring out to push each of those values into an array.

```
my_array = []
my_array.push(my_var)
=> ["123, 222, 333, 444, 555, 1024, 44444"]
puts my_array[0]
=> 1
```

I am trying to get:

```
puts my_array[0]
=> 123
```

Comment: Where does that string come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`String#split`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-split) method to get the array of *strings* first,then convert them to *integer* using [`String#to_i`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-to_i) :

```
ary = my_var.split(",").map(&:to_i)
# => [123, 222, 333, 444, 555, 1024, 44444]
p ary[0]
# => 123
```

Or use [`String#scan`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-scan) method

```
ary = my_var.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
# => [123, 222, 333, 444, 555, 1024, 44444]
p ary[0]
# => 123
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use Ruby's [`CSV`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) class:

```
require "csv"

my_var = "123, 222, 333, 444, 555, 1024, 44444"

CSV.parse_line(my_var, converters: :numeric)
#=> [123, 222, 333, 444, 555, 1024, 44444]
```